# Parse Server Cloud Code Save Object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am attempting to query an object add 1 to the returned integer and then save this object back to my mLabs database using parse server cloud code.

I can successfully query and add 1 to the object that I would like, however I cannot figure out how to successfully save this back to the database.  I have tried many solutions all leading to a Parse Server **"request timeout"**

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("addRating", function(request, response) {

  var currentRatingQuery = new Parse.Query("StudentNotes");
  currentRatingQuery.equalTo("objectId", "Y4bBzvsHb1");
  currentRatingQuery.select("noteRating");
  currentRatingQuery.find({
    useMasterKey: true,
    success: function(results) {
      //var noteRating = results.get("noteRating");
      //noteRating += 1;
      results = Number(results);
      results += 1;
      console.log("NOTE RATINGGGGG: " + results);
      console.log("TYPE OFFFFFFF: " + typeof results);


      results.set('institution', "TEST INSTITUTION");
      results.save(null, {
        useMasterKey: true
      });
      console.log("SAVE SUCCESS", results);
      response.success("rating updated successfully.", results);

    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error("failed to add 1 to parse cloud code rating. Error: " + error); //THIS GETS CALLED
    }
  });

});
```

The code above successfully queries the database, but does not save the value back.  It results in a Parse Server "request timeout".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was syntax related there is a severe lack of syntax for parse server cloud code due to it being so similar to parse.com cloud code.  The following is the working code to retrieve an object and save the object back.

```js
Parse.Cloud.define('addNoteRating', function(request, response) {
  var SaveObject = Parse.Object.extend("StudentNotes");
  var saveObject = new Parse.Query(SaveObject);
  saveObject.equalTo("objectId", request.params.objectId);
  saveObject.first({
    useMasterKey: true,
    success: function(Objects) {
      Objects.save(null, {
        useMasterKey: true,
        success: function(object) {
          object.increment("noteRating");
          object.save();
          console.log("Cloud Code: User note rating has increased by 1.", object);
          response.success('Cloud Code: User note rating has increased by 1.');

        }
      });
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped me too, after hours and hours of debugging

Answer (score 1):

Timeout may cause by no response.
Try to add response when api failed, and see what is happened.

BTW, If you what response when increment success, response when save complete.

```js
Parse.Cloud.define('addNoteRating', function(request, response) {
  var SaveObject = Parse.Object.extend("StudentNotes");
  var saveObject = new Parse.Query(SaveObject);
  saveObject.equalTo("objectId", request.params.objectId);
  saveObject.first({
    useMasterKey: true,
    //this function will get at most one object
    success: function(object) {
      if(object){
        object.increment("noteRating");
        object.save(null,{
          //do not use master key?
          success: function(note){
            //u should wait the non-blocking call success and finish
            console.log("Cloud Code: User note rating has increased by 1.", object);
            response.success('Cloud Code: User note rating has increased by 1.');
          }, error: response.error
        });
      }else{
        response.error('this student note is not exist');  
          
      }
      
    }, error: response.error  
  });
});
```

If this object is existed, you can just rewrite your code as below

```js
Parse.Cloud.define('addNoteRating', function(request, response) {
  var SaveObject = Parse.Object.extend("StudentNotes");
  var studentNote = new SaveObject();
  studentNote.id = request.params.objectId;
  studentNote.increment("noteRating");
  //student.save(null,{useMasterKey:true}).then(
  studentNote.save().then(
    function(note){
      console.log("Cloud Code: User note rating has increased by 1.", object);
      response.success('Cloud Code: User note rating has increased by 1.');
    }, response.error
  )
});
```